# AES - user key length

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes

### Context

I'm learning the basics of ssl communication, especially AES encryption.
I read OpenSSL code and saw a pointer to something called `userkey`.

```
int private_AES_set_encrypt_key( const unsigned char *userKey , const int bits , AES_KEY *key )
```

in file "aes_core.c"

### Problem

1. Where does `userkey` come from? How is it generated?
2. I would like to know the actual size of `userkey` for the different versions of AES.

   Is that 256 / 8 = 32 for the 256 bits version, 24 for the 192 and 16 for the 128? I am a bit lost.
3. If the `userkey` length is variable, then how should I create a safe input for those which will fit the length requirement? (hash? Which?)

Comment: Yes sorry i update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. userkey = secure sequence of bytes, 128 bits = 16 bytes 256 = 32 bytes  192 = 24 bytes long, sort of password if it is easier to understand. 
   Differences between keys sizes were nicely discussed [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20/what-are-the-practical-differences-between-256-bit-192-bit-and-128-bit-aes-enc).
2. Yes
3. Length of the key is constant for the algorithm and specified in the 'bits' parameter (in bits!)

OpenSSL has two AES API: [first](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/aes/aes.h) you are dealing with, [second EVP API](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption).  Use EVP for the real non-test applications.